# How to smoothly swap two elements (bounce out old one, bounce in new one) using animate.css animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two menus that I want to be swappable using a toggle. Swapping them is no problem but I can't get the animation right.

When swapping between the two menus I would like the first menu to bounceout of the screen and the second one bouncein in the place of the first one at the same time.

I made a codepen with what I have tried so far:

https://codepen.io/twan2020/pen/OJRXMLo

How can I create a swap animation that looks smooth? Like shuffling a deck of cards, the old menu animating with bounceout while the new menu animating with bouncein at the same time.

My HTML:

```
<div class="animate__animated" id="menu1">
  This is menu 1
</div>

<div class="animate__animated" id="menu2">
  This is menu 2
</div>

<div class="toggle-switch-container">
  <div class="toggle-switch switch-vertical" id="togglemenu">
    <input id="toggle-a" type="radio" name="switch" checked="checked" value="1" />
    <label for="toggle-a">Menu 1</label>
    <input id="toggle-b" type="radio" name="switch" value="2" />
    <label for="toggle-b">Menu 2</label>
    <span class="toggle-outside">
      <span class="toggle-inside"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.toggle-switch input').on('change', function() {
    if ($('input[name=switch]:checked', '.toggle-switch').val() == 1) {
        $("#menu1").addClass('animate__bounceInDown');
        $("#menu2").addClass('animate__bounceOutDown');
        $("#menu2").css('display', 'none');
        $("#menu1").css('display', 'flex');
        $("#menu1").removeClass('animate__bounceOutUp');
        $("#menu2").removeClass('animate__bounceInDown');
        console.log('1');
    } else if ($('input[name=switch]:checked', '.toggle-switch').val() == 2) {
        $("#menu1").addClass('animate__bounceOutUp');
        $("#menu2").addClass('animate__bounceInDown');
        $("#menu1").css('display', 'none');
        $("#menu2").css('display', 'flex');
        $("#menu1").removeClass('animate__bounceInDown');
        $("#menu2").removeClass('animate__bounceOutDown');
        console.log('2');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#menu2{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `$("#menu2").css('display', 'none');` and `$("#menu1").css('display', 'none');` from your js code.

And to make the container size the same, you can toggle the height of the "hidden" menu like this:

```
  $("#menu2").css('height', '0px');
  $("#menu1").css('height', 'auto');
```

and this:

```
  $("#menu1").css('height', '0px');
  $("#menu2").css('height', 'auto');
```